# 'ld: cannot find -lurdf' when building workspace

Tags: urdf, catkin-make, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

terminal dump:

```
saul@saul-VirtualBox:~/Robotics/project5/catkin_ws$ catkin_make
Base path: /home/saul/Robotics/project5/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/saul/Robotics/project5/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/saul/Robotics/project5/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/saul/Robotics/project5/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/saul/Robotics/project5/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/saul/Robotics/project5/catkin_ws/build"
####
####
#### Running command: "make -j4 -l4" in "/home/saul/Robotics/project5/catkin_ws/build"
####
[ 75%] Built target robot_sim
[ 87%] Linking CXX executable /home/saul/Robotics/project5/catkin_ws/devel/lib/robot_sim/robot_sim_bringup
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lurdf
```

CMakeLists.txt for the build:

```
# toplevel CMakeLists.txt for a catkin workspace
# catkin/cmake/toplevel.cmake

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)

set(CATKIN_TOPLEVEL TRUE)

# search for catkin within the workspace
set(_cmd "catkin_find_pkg" "catkin" "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}")
execute_process(COMMAND ${_cmd}
  RESULT_VARIABLE _res
  OUTPUT_VARIABLE _out
  ERROR_VARIABLE _err
  OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE
  ERROR_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE
)
if(NOT _res EQUAL 0 AND NOT _res EQUAL 2)
  # searching fot catkin resulted in an error
  string(REPLACE ";" " " _cmd_str "${_cmd}")
  message(FATAL_ERROR "Search for 'catkin' in workspace failed (${_cmd_str}): ${_err}")
endif()

# include catkin from workspace or via find_package()
if(_res EQUAL 0)
  set(catkin_EXTRAS_DIR "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/${_out}/cmake")
  # include all.cmake without add_subdirectory to let it operate in same scope
  include(${catkin_EXTRAS_DIR}/all.cmake NO_POLICY_SCOPE)
  add_subdirectory("${_out}")

else()
  # use either CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH explicitly passed to CMake as a command line argument
  # or CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH from the environment
  if(NOT DEFINED CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH)
    if(NOT "$ENV{CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH}" STREQUAL "")
      string(REPLACE ":" ";" CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH $ENV{CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH})
    endif()
  endif()

  # list of catkin workspaces
  set(catkin_search_path "")
  foreach(path ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH})
    if(EXISTS "${path}/.catkin")
      list(FIND catkin_search_path ${path} _index)
      if(_index EQUAL -1)
        list(APPEND catkin_search_path ${path})
      endif()
    endif()
  endforeach()

  # search for catkin in all workspaces
  set(CATKIN_TOPLEVEL_FIND_PACKAGE TRUE)
  find_package(catkin QUIET
    NO_POLICY_SCOPE
    PATHS ${catkin_search_path}
    NO_DEFAULT_PATH NO_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH)
  unset(CATKIN_TOPLEVEL_FIND_PACKAGE)

  if(NOT catkin_FOUND)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "find_package(catkin) failed. catkin was neither found in the workspace nor in the CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH. One reason may be that no ROS setup.sh was sourced before.")
  endif()
endif()

catkin_workspace()
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/263172/%27ld:-cannot-find--lurdf%27-when-building-workspace/) by [saul](https://answers.ros.org/users/30637/saul/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2017-06-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-05**:
Most likely because you've a `target_link_libraries(.. urdf)` somewhere?

Without seeing your `CMakeLists.txt` this is going to be really hard to diagnose.

Please copy/paste it into your question (*edit* it, don't post an answer). Please also remove all the boilerplate comments from it.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-05**:
That is not the `CMakeLists.txt` for your package, but the one in `catkin_ws/src`.

I think we'll need the one in `catkin_ws/src/robot_sim`.

**Comment by [saul](https://answers.ros.org/users/30637/saul/) on 2017-06-10**:
Thanks for your help.  I am new to this stuff.  I am taking an on-line Robotics class from EdX.  The CMakeList.txt file provided the course administrators pointed to the /opt/ros/indigo/lib.  I have kinetic installed.  It was an easy fix.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-10**:
Can you please link us to that online class? `CMakeLists.txt` should not need to `link_directories(..)` directly to `/opt/ros/indigo/lib`, and also should not do a `target_link_libraries(.. urdf)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks for your help.I am taking an on-line Robotics class from EdX. The CMakeList.txt file provided the course administrators pointed to the /opt/ros/indigo/lib. I have kinetic installed. It was an easy fix.

---

Originally posted by [saul](https://answers.ros.org/users/30637/saul/) with karma: 26 on 2017-06-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1